# Hiding action in url (mvc 4 web application)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a module called News as Area. In NewsAreaRegistration I have

```
context.MapRoute(
            "NewsShow",
            "News/{controller}/{friendlyUrlName}/{idNews}",
            new { controller = "Show", action = "Index", friendlyUrlName = "", idNews = "" }
        );
```

In my view (in main View folder) I use RouteUrl method to enforce my custom route

```
@Url.RouteUrl("NewsShow", new { controller = "Show",  action = "Index", friendlyUrlName = FriendlyURL.URLFriendly(true, Model.News.Data.ElementAt(0).Title), idNews = Model.News.Data.ElementAt(0).IdNews})"
```

What I would like to do is have a route like this www.something.com/News/Show/bla-bla-bla/9
without action name Index that I have in Show controller. I tried literaly all permutations of this example and nothing worked. Is this even possible?

Comment: Just wondering why you are not using @Html.ActionLink?

Comment: Becuase I want to enforce to which route to map

Comment: I tried that. I specify only controller, only action, none and nothing worked...so quite strange as i saw on the net similar problems and people had quite success.

Comment: Oh...look at that...I tried data-link="@Url.Action("Index", "Show", new { area = "News", friendlyUrlName = FriendlyURL.URLFriendly(true, Model.News.Data.ElementAt(0).Title), idNews = Model.News.Data.ElementAt(0).IdNews})" and it worked well. the problem is that now url looks like http://localhost:39865/News/Show?friendlyUrlName=kr-neki-2&idNews=9 instead SEO friendly.

Comment: Yes its great for generating SEO friendly links...also check @Html.RouteLink. I use it for the same purpose when I need SEO links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I tried this out....

Routing table: (before default)

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Hidden",
            url: "News/{controller}/{friendlyUrlName}/{idNews}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", friendlyUrlName = "", idNews = ""});

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In the View:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("Hidden", new { friendlyUrlName = "Dude-Check-It-Out", idNews = 12 })
```

in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(string friendlyUrlName, int idNews)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to kick-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";
            ViewBag.UrlName = friendlyUrlName;
            ViewBag.NewsId = idNews;
            return View();
        }
```

and I got this..

```
/News/Home/Dude-Check-It-Out/12
```

URL I go to:

```
http://localhost:49840/News/Home/Dude-Check-It-Out/12
```

I also changed my default route to something else to ensure that this wasn't using the default route. Let me know if this helped :)

Comment: But if you put breakpoint in Index action...does it go inside when you click url?

Comment: yep.. i even display the values on the page as well.

Comment: updated my answer to show you all the code around my example. scrum meeting time ill be back in few to see if you got it figured out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you put this route before default one? Route position is important, from top to bottom.

Comment: I use RouteUrl to avoid this problem

Comment: @TheMentor `RouteUrl` used for url generation, on client it will be simple link

Comment: Yes I want that. I want links like that www.something.com/News/Show/bla-bla-bla/9 and I want to hide action method. This works www.something.com/News/Show/Index/bla-bla-bla/9...this doesn't www.something.com/News/Show/bla-bla-bla/9

Comment: @TheMentor I understand you, I was taking about even `www.something.com/News/Show/bla-bla-bla/9` was generated with 'RouteUrl', it wont work, if your routes are at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Ok...I managed to work somehow.

In my NewsAreaRegistration I had to move NewsShow route before default. Not sure why, becuase RouteUrl should map excatly to NewsShow.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
  context.MapRoute(
    "NewsShow",
    "News/{controller}/{friendlyUrlName}/{idNews}",
    new { controller = "Show", action = "Index", friendlyUrlName = "", idNews = "" }
  );

  context.MapRoute(
    "News_default",
    "News/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
  );
}
```

This is my RouteUrl now (notice I had to write controller.Not sure exactly why either:

```
@Url.RouteUrl(
  "NewsShow", new { controller = "Show", friendlyUrlName = FriendlyURL.URLFriendly(true, Model.News.Data.ElementAt(0).Title), idNews = Model.News.Data.ElementAt(0).IdNews }
);
```

Comment: Hmm.. my answer and webdevelopers answers were both valid from what you are saying.. if nothing else... webdeveloper should get credit as you are describing the answer he gave.. though I did give a full example.. just saying.. giving creds helps motivate people to help more.